# Simple regex for C++

Tags: regex

I'm new to regexes and I'm trying to find a regex that matches `:randomNumberOfWhitespacesOrNothing:`

I've tried something like this `:([\s\S]*):` but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you only need whitespaces, why use `\S` (=any non-whitespace)? Use `:(\s*):`. Please explain why "it didn't work". How should it work?

Comment: It matched everything in between `::`. Your regex works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\S` pattern matches *any non-whitespace* symbol. Remove it from your character class and use

```
:(\s*):
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m9kY4Q/1)

**Details**:

- `:` - a colon
- `(\s*)` -  capturing group with ID 1 that matches 0+ (due to `*` quantifier) whitespace symbols
- `:` - a colon.